# В Андроид-приложении GoogleSignInAccount возвращает ApiException.getStatusCode() == 10

Tags: java, android, google-account

При старте приложения создаю экземпляр GoogleSignInClient следующим образом:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build(); 
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

При этом в server_client_id живет строка, полученная через credentials.json при регистрации приложения в учетке гугла. По кнопке пытаюсь авторизоваться:

```
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(); 
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

После выбора учетки в активности авторизации в onActivityResult получаю Task и из него аккаунт:

```
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
```

но вызов последней строчки вызывает ApiException с кодом ошибки 10

Answer (score 0):

Я предложу вам временный способ решение вашей проблемы.

Зайдите в https://console.developers.google.com/ в свой проект.

В разделе `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` -> `Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in)` скопируйте `Client ID` и подставьте его.

На данный момент у меня такое временное решение проблемы. Пока не нашел где я не правильно добавил к FireBase

А так же посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452779/developer-error-this-application-is-misconfigured-google-sign-in-on-firebase